Keyboard shortcut to go to profile page is broken
The keyboard shortcut to reach the user profile page is not working because the top bar's anchor element to the user's profile page doesn't have any of the expected classnames, profile-link or profile-me. Please fix this. Either change the expected classnames, or give one of the expected classnames to the user link element in the top bar.

As a temporary1 fix, I created a userscript which enables the navigation to your own profile using keyboard shortcuts.
On StackApps: Keyboard navigation to "my profile"
Also, the installation section reproduced here for ease of access:

Installation
Direct install (GitHub)
See the code on GitHub
(For instructions how to install userscripts: see the tag wiki here)
Code:
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Keyboard navigation to profile
// @description     Allow keyboard navigation to personal profile (G->P)
// @namespace       https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
// @grant           none
// @inject-into     page
// @match           https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://superuser.com/*
// @match           https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match           https://askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://stackapps.com/*
// @match           https://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match           https://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://meta.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/*
// @version         1.0
// @author          VLAZ
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
  const userProfile = document.querySelector("#user-profile-button img");

  if (!userProfile) {
      console.warn("Could not find a user profile on the page. The fix for keyboard navigation is not active.")
      return;
  }

  userProfile.classList.add("profile-me");
})();


1 just for 6-8 weeks

why #user-profile-button img instead of #user-profile-button?

@starball because I spent, like, few seconds on this
